# Data in my table product_commandes are not insert

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, object, jpa

I'm facing a display issue with my PostgreSQL database.
Im a beginner with java so i ask help here and i hope to have some explanation to understand what happening.
To explain the problem, I have two classes (Product and Order) with a @ManyToMany relationship.

```
class Product (produit)
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Commande> commande;

class Commande (literraly order)
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "commande",targetEntity = Produit.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL },fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Produit> listProduit;
```

In the database, I have an intermediate table (product_order) that should manage the many-to-many relationship.
When I insert a new order, the order gets added to the database in the order table but not in the product_order table, which should contain the order's ID and the respective product ID.

I 've tried to change the annotation relation but i ve the same result

Stultuske

This is the methode who add a order

```
public static void addCommande(Session session, Transaction transaction,Client client, List<Produit> listProduit){
    
    Commande newCommande = new Commande();
    


     
        newCommande.setClient(client);
        newCommande.setListProduit(listProduit);
        
        
        
        try {
            
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(newCommande);
            System.out.println("La commande a été ajouté avec succès");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            session.close();
        }
        
    }
```

This is my main class

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getOpenSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        
        
        Client client = ClientDAO.getSingleClientById(session,transaction,5l);
        
        Produit table = ProduitDAO.getSingleProduitById(session,transaction,2l);
        Produit chaise = ProduitDAO.getSingleProduitById(session,transaction,1l);
        
        List<Produit> nouvelleListProduit = new ArrayList<Produit>();
        

        nouvelleListProduit = CommandeDAO.addProduit(nouvelleListProduit, chaise);
        nouvelleListProduit = CommandeDAO.addProduit(nouvelleListProduit, table);
        
        CommandeDAO.addCommande(session,transaction,client, nouvelleListProduit);
        

    }
```

This is my class Order

```
package Entity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SecondaryTable;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="commandes")
@SecondaryTable(name = "produit_commande")


public class Commande {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="id_commande")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idCommande;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_client")
    private Client client;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "commande",targetEntity = Produit.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL },fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Produit> listProduit;

    public Long getIdCommande() {
        return idCommande;
    }

    public void setIdCommande(Long idCommande) {
        this.idCommande = idCommande;
    }

    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public  void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public List<Produit> getListProduit() {
        return listProduit;
    }

    public  void setListProduit(List<Produit> listProduit) {
        this.listProduit = listProduit;
    }


}
```

And this is my class Product

```
package Entity;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="produits")
public class Produit {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="id_produit")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_produit;
    

    @Column(name = "nom_produit")
    private String nom_produit;
    
    
    @Column(name = "is_dispo")
    private Boolean is_dispo;
    
    
    @Column(name="prix")
    private Double prix;
    
    
    @Column(name="created_at")
    private LocalDate created_at;
    
    
    @Column(name="quantite")
    private int quantite;
    

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Commande> commande;


    public Long getId_produit() {
        return id_produit;
    }


    public void setId_produit(Long id_produit) {
        this.id_produit = id_produit;
    }


    public String getNom_produit() {
        return nom_produit;
    }


    public void setNom_produit(String nom_produit) {
        this.nom_produit = nom_produit;
    }


    public Boolean getIs_dispo() {
        return is_dispo;
    }


    public void setIs_dispo(Boolean is_dispo) {
        this.is_dispo = is_dispo;
    }


    public Double getPrix() {
        return prix;
    }


    public void setPrix(Double prix) {
        this.prix = prix;
    }


    public LocalDate getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }


    public void setCreated_at(LocalDate created_at) {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }


    public int getQuantite() {
        return quantite;
    }


    public void setQuantite(int quantite) {
        this.quantite = quantite;
    }
    
    public List<Commande> getCommande() {
        return commande;
    }


    public void setCommande(List<Commande> commande) {
        this.commande = commande;
    }

}

Class CommandeDAO

    package EntityDAO;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Set;
    
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    
    import Entity.Client;
    import Entity.Commande;
    import Entity.Produit;
    import Utilitaire.HibernateUtil;
    
    public class CommandeDAO {
    
        
        public static void addCommande(Session session, Transaction transaction,Client client, List<Produit> listProduit){
            
            Commande newCommande = new Commande();
            
            
            newCommande.setClient(client);
            newCommande.setListProduit(listProduit);
            
            
            
            try {
                
                transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                session.save(newCommande);
                System.out.println("La commande a été ajouté avec succès");
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                transaction.rollback();
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                session.close();
            }
            
        }
        
        public static List<Produit> addProduit(List<Produit> listProduit, Produit produit) {
            
            listProduit.add(produit);
            
            return listProduit;
                    
        }
    
    
        
        
    
    }
```

Class Product DAO

```
package EntityDAO;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;


import Entity.Produit;
import Utilitaire.HibernateUtil;

    public class ProduitDAO {
        
        
        
        public static  void insertProduit(Session session, Transaction transaction,String nom_produit,Double prix, int quantity) {
            
            Produit newProduit = new Produit();
            
            newProduit.setNom_produit(nom_produit);
            newProduit.setPrix(prix);
            newProduit.setQuantite(quantity);
    
            
            
            try {
                
                transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                session.save(newProduit);
                session.flush();
                System.out.println("Ce produit a été ajouté avec succès");
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                transaction.rollback();
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                session.close();
            }
            
        }
        
        public static Produit getSingleProduitById(Session session, Transaction transaction,Long id_produit) {
            
            String hql = "SELECT p FROM Produit p WHERE p.id_produit = :id_produit" ;
            Query<Produit> query = session.createQuery(hql).setParameter("id_produit", id_produit);
            
            
            Produit produit = query.getSingleResult();
            
            System.out.println("Le produit selectionné est " + produit.getNom_produit());
    
            return produit;
        }
        
        public static void editProduit(Session session, Transaction transaction,Produit produit) {
            
            try {
                
                transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                session.update(produit);
                
                transaction.commit();
                System.out.println("Ce produit a été editer avec succès");
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                transaction.rollback();
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        
        public static void deleteProduit(Session session, Transaction transaction,Produit produit) {
            
            try {
                
                transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                session.delete(produit);
                transaction.commit();
                System.out.println("Ce produit a été supprimé avec succès");
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                transaction.rollback();
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                session.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: maybe you should also show the code you use to add data. if you're just doing something in the lines of "insert into produit x, x values y, y;" ...

Comment: @Stultuske i va answer with code

Comment: I don't see any code for CommandeDAO. Did you make addProduit and addCommande static methods? If so, why? I also see nothing related to a product_owner table.

Comment: @Stultuske I do static method to call them directy in my main I put a secondary table product_order in my class commande